# Boostrap Flex: What is the difference between row and flex-row, flex-sm-row, etc

Tags: bootstrap-4

I understand the concept of flex sm, md, lg columns but not when applied to rows. What does flex row do? and what do the sizes sm, md, lg mean when applied to a flex row?

Comment: what do you mean with "a flex row"? `<div class="row">` creates one row with flexbox css properties... the rest is flexbox knowledge...?  or do you mean `flex-row` ? this just sets the `flex-flow` property to `row` and has nothing to do with row and col- classes.

Comment: If ```<div class="row">``` creates a row with flexbox css properties, then when would you need to use ```flex-row```? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short Answer** - `.row` is only a container for grid `col`. However, `flex-row`, `flex-column`, etc.. can be used for *any* flexbox elements (not just the grid rows and columns).

**Long Answer**

The [flexbox direction utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#direction) can be used to responsively change the **direction** of flexbox children (regardless of the children being grid columns or other content). There are 4 flexbox directions:
**row**, **row-reverse**, **column** and **column-reverse**

For example, a flexbox parent `<div>` that contains 4 child `<span>` elements. You can make the children **column direction** on xs, **row direction** on sm and up:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-sm-row flex-column">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
</div>
```

Of course they can *also* be used to override the default flex row direction of the grid `.row`. For example, reverse the column order on lg and up:

```
<div class="row flex-lg-row-reverse">
    <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">3</div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/sSgebPyncz

**Another way to look at it:**

These classes are used to responsively control column **width**:
`col-12`, `col-lg-4`, `col-md-5`, etc...

These classes are used to responsively control **flexbox direction**:
`flex-row`, `flex-column`, `flex-md-row-reverse`, etc...

Comment: Hi @Zim, thank you for the detailed answer, however I am still unsure between the 'size' differences for row, meaning sm, md and lg

Comment: `sm`, `md` and `lg` are responsive breakpoint sizes - they represent **viewport widths**, NOT column or row width.